# Variable assignments done in function parameter declaration

Tags: javascript, php, function, parameters

I'm working on maintaining a software written in PHP and Javascript and I stumbled onto something I was not familiar with:

```
class xyz{
var $foo1 = ' ';
var $foo2 = false;
var $foo3 = ' ';
function xyz($newVariable, $foo1 = 'rabbit', $foo2 = true, $foo3 = 'bird') {
...
}}
```

And elsewhere in the code:

```
function bleh(){
xyz('hello);
}
```

Why are variables being assigned in the parameter fields in my first function instead of directly in the constructor? Why does bleh call xyz with only 1 parameter if there are 4 in its declaration?

Thank you!

Comment: Because the method needs default values for operating in its body, rather than the class.

Comment: function xyz is declared with default paramaters (i.e., $foo1='rabbit', etc).  When xyz is called from within bleh() with only 1 parameter, the remaining 3 take their default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are known as default parameters.  If the parameters are missing (unset) they will default to the value in the parameter.
Since Function overloading isn't allowed in PHP this is a good work around.

Comment: Thank you. What must I do if I want to call "xyz" and redefine $foo3 while keeping the default values for $foo1 and $foo2?

Comment: Reorder the params.  otherwise xyz('val', 'rabbit', true, 'newValue)